# Capture CMOS video with FPGA, encode and send over Ethernet

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, fpga, transport-stream

I am planning a open source university project for my students based on Zynq Xilinx FPGA that will capture CMOS video, encode it into transport stream and send it over Ethernet to remote PC. Basically I want to design yet another IP camera. I have strong FPGA experience, but lack knowledge regarding encoding and transfering video data. Here is my plan:

1. Connect CMOS camera to FPGA, recieve video frames and save them to external DDR memory, verify using HDMI output to monitor. I have no problems with that.
2. I understand that I have to compress my video stream for example to H.264 format and put into transport stream. Here I have little knowledge and require some hints.
3. After I form transport stream I can send it over network using UDP packets. I have working hardware solution that reads data from FIFO and sends it to remote PC as UDP papckets.
4. And finally I plan to receive and play video using ffmpeg library.

   `ffplay udp://localhost:5678`

My question is basically regarding 2 step. How do I convert pixel frames to transport stream? My options are:

1. Use commercial IP, like

   - http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/1-4iso32.html
   - http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/1-1lk9j1.html#overview

Here I doubt that they are free to use and we don't have much funds.

2. Use open cores like

   - http://sourceforge.net/projects/hardh264/ - here core generates only h264 output, but how to encapsulate it into transport stream?
   - I have searched opencores.org but with no success on this topic
   - Maybe somebody knows some good open source relevant FPGA projects?
3. Develop harware encoder by myself using Vivado HLS (C Language). But here is the problem that I don't know the algorithm. Maybe I could gig ffmpeg or Cisco openh264 library and find there a function that converts raw pixel frames to H.264 format and then puts it into transport stream? Any help would be appriciated here also.

Also I am worried about format compatibility of stream I might generate inside FPGA and the one expected at host by ffplay utility. Any help, hints, links and books are appriciated!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already have good hold on to computationally intensive tasks (Video capture, H264 Encoder). Only part that you need help is about packing the enocder output into transportable stream. This task is not so computationally intensive, I guess you can afford this task on dual Cortex-A9 cores of Zynq. Actually, encoder is the one that converts raw pixel frames to H.264 format. Streaming methods are just about attaching a header to the output of encoder.

Comment: Also, I guess you know that H264 encoder accepts input in YUV format only. You may want to use YUV 4:2:0 format. So, you need a color-conversion module between video capture and encoder

Comment: I do not know what kind of scope you have in mind for your project, but I was involved in a project implementing an h.264 decoder in hardware and that was quite a big project. Actually, fours students each did two implementations, one in BSV and one in Verilog, and it took months for each one.

Comment: Hi! Have you succeeded at the task? We need to build something similar for our project. Can you please contact me here, at telegram t.me/caffeinum or via email aleksey at bykhun.com?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any open source hardware h.264 encoders, but I was giving advice to someone who was moving some of the heavy computational parts of a software encoder into an FPGA. It might have been openh264.

I would not recommend ffmpeg for this project, because it implements so many protocols. There are enough options just in h.264 without having to worry about other standards.

As for container formats, MPEG4 boxes are pretty simple, so adding transport encapsulation should be pretty straightforward. I'm thinking of the Quicktime 4cc encapsulation.

I would suggest MPEG DASH, because you can encapsulate each video frame into a separate box (a MOOF movie fragment). However, wrapping encoded data in containers is not computationally intensive. Here is some software that deals with that container format:
 https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/

Rather than implementing the entire encoder in hardware, you could focus on the computationally intensive parts, which you can find by profiling the software as it runs. The deblocking filter is one such function, and it is used both for encoding and decoding.

Good luck with your project!